# PHP/innerHTML using two while-loops results in database outputting partly outside of the html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to output my database data into an html table. With the output of the last column of that table being a bit special. Because it needs to have a specific color based on the integer-data of the last database value.

The first three column in my html table get the right database table, the last one also outputs the value "green" (which is not correct according to the values but this is not the problem). The problem is that I am using two while loops (PHP). One for checking all the rows of column Status from my database. and a while loop to get all the data into the html table.

No all my "status" data outputs partly outside of my html table. Please what can be the exact problem and how can I solve this?

mycode:

```
<table class="scroll">
    <thead style="background-color: #99E1D9; color: #705D56;">
        <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name Client</th>
            <th>Last Update</th>
            <th style="margin-left: 21%; padding-left: 0%;">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="hoverTable" style="font-size: 11pt;">

<?php

    //connect ot database
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
     mysql_select_db('patientdb');

     //get data from data base for the first three columns in the table.
    $query = "SELECT id, name, date FROM clients";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

// get data from database for the last column in the table and the conditional statement for status color.
    $query2 = "SELECT status FROM clients";
    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    if (!empty ($result2)) {
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo $row2['status'] . "<br />";
    }
    }


    //fetch results per row into the table.
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Loop through results
    echo "<tr> 

            <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['naam'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>


            <td style='padding-left: 20%;'>";

                // check of the data from 'status' per condition and assign it a color.
                if ($row2 > 60 && $row2 < 70) {
                    echo "red";
                } elseif ($row2 > 50 && $row2 < 60) { 
                    echo "yellow";
                } else { 
                    echo "green";
                }
                echo "</td>

         </tr>"; 
    }
    //close database connection
    mysql_close(); 
?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

please see this image for what my current situation looks like:

[image]

How can I solve this issue? So firstly my db_table 'status' values don't show up outside of the htmlTable. and the last htmlTable-column "status" color values are according to the conditional statement I have written in the last `<td>` ?

EDIT: Solution

```
<table class="scroll">
    <thead style="background-color: #99E1D9; color: #705D56;">
        <tr>
           <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name Client</th>
            <th>Last Update</th>
            <th style="margin-left: 21%; padding-left: 0%;">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="hoverTable" style="font-size: 11pt;">

<?php

    //connect ot database
    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
     mysql_select_db('patientdb');

     //get data from data base for the first three columns in the table.
    $query = "SELECT id, name, date, status FROM clients";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    //fetch results per row into the table.
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Loop through results
    echo "<tr> 

            <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['naam'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $row['datum'] . "</td>


            <td style='padding-left: 20%;'>";

                // check of the data from 'status' per condition and assign it a color.
                if ($row['status'] > 60 && $row['status'] < 70) {
                    echo "red";
                } elseif ($row['status'] > 50 && $row['status'] < 60) { 
                    echo "yellow";
                } else { 
                    echo "green";
                }
                echo "</td>

         </tr>"; 
    }
    //close database connection
    mysql_close(); 
?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: parse classes and use css might be a way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it would be a lot easier if you select the status in your first query 
`SELECT id, name, date, status FROM clients`

and .. shouldn't it be `if($row2['status'] ..` in the second loop ?

Comment: Oh nice, I am going to try this bro. Brb. I thought of this, but I thought it was not possible. Because I did not know someone could use $row2['status'].

Comment: But than I have to use if($row['status'] without the 2 right?

Comment: but even if you use `$row2['status']` i don't think it will work, because `$row2` will have the last value in it and won't change, you should go for the first option, add the status in your query and use only one loop

Comment: yes if you add `status` in your query you will use `$row['status']`

Comment: Dude! I love you! It worked. I used "$row['status']". I have been going at it for 2 days.. finally.

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Comment: Also, stop using mysql_xxx, is deprecated, use mysqli_xxx or PDO. GL

Comment: @Asfo Please see my EDIT, how would you use mysqli in my solution-code? I am new to this, learning as I go :)

Comment: Just add the -> i <- after mysql ...like "mysqli_query" and create an instance of the connection like you did (in a non oop way):  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass', 'database'); and pass it as an arg in every "mysqli_query" like: mysqli_query($connection, "SQL"); Check the docs :D they're really easy to understand. GL learning. [PHP DOCS](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php)